Impossible to register android device in Azure Notification Hub
I am trying to update my platform (mobile app in xamarin forms and backend in .net7) to set notifications on android devices via the google Fcmv1 system. Unfortunately I can't register the device on my Azure Notification Hub. I tried the various codes that I found on the official documentation but without success. My app sends token to backend and backend tries registration on hub. I don't get any error but anyway I don't find device on hub. I tried
var nhClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, HubName);
var installation = new Installation
                {
                    InstallationId = $"{device.ID}",
                    Platform = NotificationPlatform.FcmV1,
                    PushChannel = device.Token,
                    PushChannelExpired = false,
                    UserId = $"{device.ID}"
                };

await nhClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);

and also
var nhClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, HubName);
var tags = new HashSet<string> { "tag1", "tag2" };
FcmV1RegistrationDescription registration = await nhClient.CreateFcmV1NativeRegistrationAsync(deviceToken, tags);

and also
var nhClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, HubName);
var installation = new FcmV1Installation($"{device.ID}", device.Token);
await nhClient.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);

The hub works correctly for both iOS and android with the old GCM system that now no longer working but the device registration occurs correctly using this code
var installation = new Installation
                {
                    InstallationId = $"{device.ID}",
                    Platform = NotificationPlatform.Fcm,
                    PushChannel = device.Token, 
                    PushChannelExpired = false,
                    UserId = $"{device.ID}"
                };

I'm really frustrated about this problem. Any idea?
Thanks
I tried code found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1533052/where-i-can-download-new-version-of-microsoft-azur and other code found on web (pretty much the same of official doc)
I expect to find registered device on hub

I had same problem.This code worked for me
//device is my object contains tag and pushchanel
 if(device.Platform.ToLower() == "apns")
            {
                await _notificationHub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(device.Token, device.tags);
            }
            else //fcmv1
            {
                await _notificationHub.CreateFcmV1NativeRegistrationAsync(device.Token, device.tags);
            }

